# Partial derivative product rule: formula and proof?

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, operator-theory

There's a formula I don't know the proof for, but it asserts for differential operators that

$\partial_x f(x)\partial_x = f'(x)\partial_x + f(x) \partial_x^2$ (on the domain of sufficiently differentiable functions).

I have two questions related to this:

One, how can we prove the combinations of operators on both sides of the equation are equivalent?

And two, suppose we have a more general case:

$$\partial_x f(x) \partial_y.$$ Does this expand out to

$$\partial_x f(x) \partial_y = f'(x) \partial_y + f(x) \partial_y \partial_x?$$

How can we prove the partial-derivative version of this operator formula?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove product rule applies to differential operators?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523986/prove-product-rule-applies-to-differential-operators)

Comment: No, that does not answer the proof component of the ordinary case, and certainly does not address the partial derivative case in any way.

Comment: As answered in the Duplicate: apply those formulas to a function $g(x)$ resp. $h(y)$ and use the product rule. User `askquestions2` deleted that duplicate. What a double coincidence.

Comment: I don't think that qualifies as a proof. Aside from the fact that no rigorous definition of anything was applied, functions of a real variable $x$ commute under multiplication. The operations multiplying by $g(x)$ and $\partial_x$ certainly do not.